# Setting for Thunderbird to not store old email attachment on my harddrive

Tags: thunderbird

I use Thunderbird with Gmail. I would like to store all data on Gmail. However I would prefer if attachments of old (longer than month) emails aren't stored on my harddrive. Is there a way to do this in Thunderbird?